# How to remove white space on the side of my website

Tags: html, css, overflow, whitespace

I have a website (https://olsenspkg.com) that has white space on the right hand side of every page. Currently I have tried this to solve it:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It only fixes it on chrome though. Safari still acts like I haven't put that code in.

[Regular Site View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAFfP.png)

[White Space on the Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bowYh.png)

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden` is not a good idea. Find the element that overflows and deal with it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `#searchBar` from your header.
You gave it `left:478px` but it has position:relative. So it still occupies space. By giving it left `478px` it made your website 478px larger to the right.

So remove that and position it using other solutions. Like a simple `#searchBar { text-align:right }` i guess will do the trick.

Also try to avoid using `overflow-x: hidden` on `body` . You never know what problems you might cause. Always in this scenarios try to find the element that is causing this unwanted overflow and deal with that specific element.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai. That solved the problem on almost every page for me. The only pages I have problems on now is the parts tables (https://olsenspkg.com/parts-catalog/brands/weldotron.html). FYI, you might have to clear your cache to see the updated style sheet, although you probably know that already.

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured out that my .container inside the .time-line-parts needed to be set to 100% width. Thanks so much. HUGE help!

Answer (score 0):

This element is overflown:

```
<div id="searchBar">
```

The width is the same as parents div. Change width to 300px or change that rendering completely.

[Overflown div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDRTH.png)